# if $a,b\in A$, $a\mid b$ then $f(a)\mid f(b)$ we have $\exists m\in A : f(m)=m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

suppose $n\in \Bbb N$ and $A$ is the set of divisors of $n$ and $f:A\to A$ is function such that:

if $a,b\in A$, $a\mid b$ then $f(a)\mid f(b)$

how to prove : $ \exists m\in A : f(m)=m$

it's seems that it has one solution with Pigeonhole principle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: :what are trying?

Comment: "$A$ is a set" or "$A$ is the set" OR there are other constrains? If "$A$ is a set", then consider $n = 6, A = \{2,3\}$ and the map $f: 2 \mapsto 3, 3 \mapsto 2$, $f$ doesn't have a fixed point.

Comment: Try the case $n=p^r$ with $p$ prime first. Then $f(p^k)=p^{g(k)}$ where $g$ goes from $\{0,\ldots,r\}$ to istelf and is nondecreasing. Try to construct such a $g$ without fixed point...you can't! Consider the orbit of $0$. If there is no fixed point, $0,g(0),g(g(0)),\ldots, g^r(g(0))$ is an increasing sequence of $r+1$ elements in a set of $r$ elements. Impossible. As pointed out by dtldarek, the same argument works in the general case: if $f(1)=1$, you're done. If not, and if there is no fixed point, the forward orbit of $1$ is injective in a finite set. Impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
 Consider the sequence $1\mid f(1), f(1)\mid f(f(1)),f(f(1))\mid f(f(f(1))), \ldots$

Further hint:
 Assume that $1\neq f(1), f(1)\neq f(f(1)),f(f(1))\neq f(f(f(1)))\ldots$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, excellent, +1.

Comment: This is a special case of the [Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster–Tarski_theorem)

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

- The divisibility relation is a partial order, and the [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29) corresponding to the set of divisors of $n$ is [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice).
- In this setting $\forall a,b\in A.\ a \mid b \implies f(a) \mid f(b)$ means that $f$ is [order-preserving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_order_theory).
- Your result is a conclusion from [Knaster-Tarski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem). For example, take some $x \in A$, does this sequence $\langle x,f(x),f(f(x)),f^{(3)}(x),\ldots \rangle$ converge?

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general result that fits the problem.

- Let B be a finite set (B $\subset \mathbb{N}$) such that there exists u (his greatest element) and v (his smallest element) $ \in$ B that verifies $\forall$ b $\in$ B , v | b | u
- Let $\textit{f}$ :B $\rightarrow $B such that if $a,b\in B$, $a|b$ then $f(a)|f(b)$
- Let us  prove by strong induction on card(B) that $\textit{f}$ has at least one fixed point
- If card(B) = 1, it's trivial
- Suppose the result true for all k $\in$ {0,1,..,n}

If card(B) = n+1 ,

- if f(v)=v then it's done
- else, v | $\textit{f}$(v) implies that v < $\textit{f}$(v)

Let B' = B \ {b $\in B$/ $\textit{f}$(b)=v}

u $\in$ B' (if not $\textit{f}$(u)=v implies $\textit{f}$(v)|v which is absurd

since v< $\textit{f}$(v))

- Then B' is a finite set that verifies previous hypothesises, with card(B') < n+1

By our assumption from below, $\textit{f}$ with B' as inputs set has at least one fixed point m

- Since B' $\subset$ B , m is also a fixed point for f with B as inputs set
- Hence the result with card(B) = n+1
- Conclusion: the result holds for any B with the previous hypothesises
- Here, u=n and v= 1